# JToolBarHelper custom button to run a task from another component?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

Is there any solution to add a custom toolbar button with JToolBarHelper::custom() (Or any other functions), which runs a task from another component?

Edit:
Im writing a Plugin which adds a Toolbar Button to a Core component (com_users).
I've added the button using onBeforeRender system event. but I cant send List Form Data to a task or any place that I can Change.

Comment: you can't do that bcoz toolbar button using current component option,controller etc, Only option is to use as a url

Comment: @JobinJose is right, you can't do that with JToolBarHelper::custom() button.

Comment: I dont insist in using JToolBarHelper!

Answer (score 6):

Well that my be not the best solution, but you can set redirect in your own controllers task, to execute in another component's controller.

Let's say you create a button:

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('controllerName.taskName', 'icon', 'icon over', 'Button text', false, false);
```

Then in your controllerName controller you create a method:

```
function taskName()
{
    $this->setRedirect('index.php?option=com_SomeComponent&task=anotherController.anotherTask');
    $this->redirect();
}
```

Comment: that is what i mean :)